# Borel measure with one point mass

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$, let $I=[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Assume $\mu$ has exactly one point mass in $I$ in the sense: $\exists x_0 \in I \backslash\{a,b\}$ s.t. $\lambda:=\mu(\{x_0\})>0$ and $\forall x \neq x_0$ $\exists \epsilon_x >0$ such that $\mu((x-\epsilon_x,x+\epsilon_x))=0$. Want to show $\mu=\lambda \delta_{x_0}$ on $I$.

For this I need to show $\mu((x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta))=\mu(\{x_0\})$ where $\delta>0$ is small. How to do this?

Comment: The notation $\mu(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ is a bit sloppy, the argument of $\mu$ is measurable set, not two numbers. To prove the assertion, show that $\mu\big([a,b]\setminus\{x_0\}\big)=0$.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the notation. Actually I started from there, don't see how to prove it. Clearly if $E\subset I$ is a closed set not containing $x_0$ then $\mu(E)=0$ because we can cover $E$ by measure $0$ sets and use compactness argument. How to show $\mu([a,x_0))=0$? So this is equivalent to the question I asked right?

Comment: You are on the right track. To finish the argument, write $[a,x_0)$ as a countable union of closed subsets. A countable union of measure zero sets is again of measure zero.

Comment: Sorry, still I don't see it. If we are away the point $x_0$ then the measure is $0$ and remains somehow to prove $\mu([x_0-\delta, x_0])=\mu(\{x_0\})$ and I'm stuck here...

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. You want to write the sets $[a,x_0)$ and $(x_0,b]$ as countable unions of closed sets of measure zero.

Comment: Oh... $[a,x_0) = \cup_{n\geq 1} [a, x_0 -\frac{1}{n}]$ works. Thank you!!!